# web element position problem

Tags: html, css, position

Make each of the two element take half of the width of their parent.

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zUqqN/

I just want the div#mapContent_coverage do not show by default,and then the div#mapContent_emap will take all the width of the "mapDiv",

when user click the img in the right,the **div#mapContent_coverage** should show,and then "**mapContent_emap" and "mapContent_coverage"** will show at the same time,and I want both of them take half of the width.

I have tried use the  float and absolute to the div,but it does not work,any idea?

BTW,I do not want the scrollbar show in the browser,for exmaple:

Now matter how do I resize the browser ,there is not scroll bar . How to make this?

[image]

### UPDATE:

The default page layout:
[image]

WHen I click the img in the right,the page should change to :
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the issue with the click and div, could you explain a bit better please?

Comment: Thanks,in fact,there is no problem(at least under my test) for the click event,I just can not make the layout.

Comment: ok, then explain a bit better how you want the layout :) your explanation is a bit confusing I would like to understand it better before finding a solution for you.

Comment: Hi,I just update my question(I make some images),hope you can understand.:) Sorry for my poor English expression.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display both set each width to 50%. To display only one set the width to 100% and hide the other.

Answer (score 0):

to hide the scroll from the browser add this CSS:

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

(I'll reply to the rest after clearing some doubts, check my comment)